# Как остановить цикл в функции main, при запуске другой асинхронной функции, например close()

Tags: python

```
async def main(self): 
    try:
        while True:
            print('hello world')
    except Exception as err:
            print(err)

async def close(self):
    #нужно что то сделать чтобы остановить цикл while в функции main
    pass
```

Comment: `while not что_то_сделано:`

Comment: `while True` в асинхронной функции уже выглядит как-то странно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53540726/python-asyncio-stop-and-start-a-task-from-another-task-without-lossing-state